# Connect Local AD with C# .Net Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

Having trouble understanding this error below in vs.net.
I'm trying to grab a logged in user account on the domain and allow them to be able to edit their phone number.

Another guy setup the AD Access, but I can't event get a logged in user name.

Pasted the code VS.NET errors on every time with the exception that I found in an online article and worked for everyone else except me.

I've verified it works using powershell but I could use some help.

THANKS!!!

```
//parse the current user's logon name as search key
            string sFilter = String.Format(
                "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))",
                User.Identity.Name.Split(new char[] { '\\' })[1]
                );

Exception User-Unhandled
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'
```

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<script language="c#" runat="server">

static string adsPath = "LDAP://dc=DOMAIN,dc=com";
        private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                SearchResult sr = FindCurrentUser(new string[] { "allowedAttributesEffective" });
                if (sr == null)
                {
                    msg.Text = "User not found...";
                    return;
                }
                int count = sr.Properties["allowedAttributesEffective"].Count;
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    string[] effectiveAttributes = new string[count];
                    foreach (string attrib in sr.Properties["allowedAttributesEffective"])
                    {
                        effectiveAttributes[i++] = attrib;
                    }
                    sr = FindCurrentUser(effectiveAttributes);
                    foreach (string key in effectiveAttributes)
                    {
                        string val = String.Empty;
                        if (sr.Properties.Contains(key))
                        {
                            val = sr.Properties[key][0].ToString();
                        }
                        GenerateControls(key, val, parent);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateControls();
            }
        }
        private SearchResult FindCurrentUser(string[] attribsToLoad)
        {
            //parse the current user's logon name as search key
            string sFilter = String.Format(
                "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))",
                User.Identity.Name.Split(new char[] { '\\' })[1]
                );
            DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(
                adsPath,
                null,
                null,
                AuthenticationTypes.Secure
                );
            using (searchRoot)
            {
                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(
                    searchRoot,
                    sFilter,
                    attribsToLoad,
                    SearchScope.Subtree
                    );
                ds.SizeLimit = 1;
                return ds.FindOne();
            }
        }
        private void GenerateControls(string attrib, string val, Control parent)
        {
            parent.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div>"));
            TextBox t = new TextBox();
            t.ID = "c_" + attrib;
            t.Text = val;
            t.CssClass = "txt";
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Text = attrib;
            l.AssociatedControlID = t.ID;
            l.CssClass = "lbl";
            parent.Controls.Add(l);
            parent.Controls.Add(t);
            parent.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
        }
        private void UpdateControls()
        {
            SearchResult sr = FindCurrentUser(new string[] { "cn" });
            if (sr != null)
            {
                using (DirectoryEntry user = sr.GetDirectoryEntry())
                {
                    foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
                    {
                        if (key.StartsWith("c_"))
                        {
                            string attrib = key.Split(new char[] { '_' })[1];
                            string val = Request.Form[key];
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                            {
                                Response.Output.Write("Updating {0} to {1}<br>", attrib, val);
                                user.Properties[attrib].Value = val;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    user.CommitChanges();
                }
            }
            btnSubmit.Visible = false;
            Response.Output.Write("<br><br><a href=\"{0}\">&lt;&nbsp;Back</a>", Request.Url);
        }
    </script>
    <style>
    .lbl
    {
        margin-left: 25px;
        clear: left;
        width: 250px;
    }
    .txt
    {
        width: 250px;
    }
</style>
</head>


<body>
    <form id="main" runat="server">
        Data for user:
        <%=User.Identity.Name%>
        <br>
        <br>
        <asp:Label ID="msg" runat="server" />
        <asp:Panel ID="parent" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Update" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why [1] ?  in   string sFilter = String.Format(
                "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName={0}))",
                User.Identity.Name.Split(new char[] { '\\' })[1]
                );

Comment: I have no clue... trying without it one min

Comment: tried it but found another s down in the code :( nice try though

Comment: sorry im reall bad at this could you type the edit you'd like to make?

Comment: What does debugger show for User.Identity.Name? You are trying to split it into array of strings by // separator. and then grab the second element of that array. if User.Identity.Name does not contain // you will not have any second element and get the error you  are getting

Comment: it says index out of rangeexception

Comment: Found this example others used online. What Im trying to due is connect to local AD and modify the phone number. Good grief I'm a sharepoint nerd not a programmer lol

Comment: Have do i give you points for helping?

Comment: What does debugger show for User.Identity.Name?

Comment: just click debug? and it gives me error. how do you do that?

Comment: That'd be huge help

Comment: place a breakpoint in front of that line and click debug

Comment: says line 60, character:9 Must mmatch source

Comment: debugger should stop on the line you set the breakpoint to. and you should be able to hover a mouse over the variable. and it should show the value

Comment: i keep trying but just not understanding. am learning new ways to troubleshoot though :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx